# Is it possible to programatically get the UID / Mac Address of a vehicle using CarPlay API?

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

When an iPhone is connected to a vehicle using CarPlay, are there any methods(by CarPlay API) that allow us to get a UID or Mac Address or any uniquely identifiable address of the vehicle.

I have looked across the CarPlay documentation and so far I've been unable to get any method that allows us to the fetch any UID of a vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no identifier for the Vehicle or CarPlay device to which you are connected.